# Ruby on Rails passing parameters to partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

This is my .erb file;

```
<% if @comment.reviewer_notes && current_user.type == "User::Reviewer"%>
      <% @comment.reviewer_notes.each do |reviewer_note| %>
        <?= reviewer_note.rating %> <-- this "works" ie prints out rating on screen
        <%= render 'partials/comments/form' %>
```

this is my .erb partial;

```
<div class="admin-rating stars clear">
  <%= reviewer_note.rating %> <-- this does not work. 
</div>
```

The error I get is;

> undefined method `reviewer_rating' for #TipComment:0x007f8b38e29328>

How do I pass in `reviewer_note.rating`?

Comment: Aside, I would change `current_user.type == ...` to user.reviewer? And add an instance method in the user model.

Comment: Read up about [locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render partial: 'reviewer_note_rating', locals: {reviewer_note: reviewer_note} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass it as a variable to Partial.

`<%= render 'partials/comments/form', note_rating: reviewer_note.rating %>`